# How do I make a list of every other ten numbers in Python

Tags: python

I need a list of integers that skips every ten numbers. I've tried to do it with brute force:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
```

This has been okay so far, but I need to go much farther and can't type in every number.

I've tried this as well, but I guess I don't understand how range works:

```
x = list(range(10))
y = list(range(20:29))
z = list(range(40:49))
final_list = x + y + z
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the contents of `final_list` and why does it not do what you want?

Comment: You need `y = list(range(20, 30))` and `z = list(range(40, 50))`.See [`range()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will probably work . Just change the range to repeat how ever many times you need it. The +20 is 10 for the first that is included and then for the ones skipped. And I increase both limits

```
my_list = []

lower=0
high=10

for n in range(5):
  x = range(lower, high)
  for n in x:
      my_list.append(n)
  lower=lower+20;
  high=high+20;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y = list(range(20:29))
z = list(range(40:49))
```

was invalided.

`range(start, end, step)`.Under your circumstance, you need these numbers: `[20, 30)`, `[40, 50)`.

So just use(like @jizhihaoSAMA said in comment):

```
x = list(range(10))
y = list(range(20, 30))
z = list(range(40, 50))
final_list = x + y + z
print(final_list)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
```

Answer (score 0):

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGygs.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGygs.png%5D)

x = list(range(11))

y = list(range(20, 30))

z = list(range(40, 50))

final_list = x + y + z

print(final_list)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a bit of math by adding the appropriate multiple of 10 to sequential numbers:

```
[ n + 10*(n//10) for n in range(100)]

# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189]
```